# How to filter products based on the category selection in the products list page?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I need to display all categories in left side and display all products list in the right side when page is loading. When you select check box for any one category, then refresh it and need to display products based on the selected category. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to **admin->Catalog-> Manage Categories->edit category->Display Settings->Is Anchor set to yes.**

Set is anchor for all category so it will display all sub category of current category in left side.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have used this one and display the all categories. but i need when you select the category and refresh the products list based on the category.

Comment: It is magento default layer functionality.If you click any category it will gives you products related to this one.

Comment: yes, I need without page refresh.